# Multiplying EditText by particular value- Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, calculator

I have to create a carparking calculator in Android Studio which will multiply the number of minutes by 3 cents. It has to contain 1 edit text, textview and button.

Comment: Welcome to SO. "I tried it in few ways but it's not working". Care to explain to us the ways? And also share some code with your approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button b;
    private EditText cells;
    private TextView ans;
    String s = "Answer";
    double c = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        cells = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_cells);
        ans = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    c = Double.parseDouble(cels.getText().toString());
                    s = Double.toString(c+((c*3)/100));
                    char ch[] = s.toCharArray();
                    ans.setText(ch, 0, ch.length)
            }
        });
   }
```

I hope you will manage `main.xml`.